# There is too much whitespace inside my border in CSS, how can I make the text fit inside borders?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KuDR.png)

Here's my code so far

```css
CSS CODE - * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  header,
  .welcome {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(237, 239, 240);
  padding: 10% 10%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.welcome {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  border: white solid 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section class="welcome" id="welcome-section">
    <h2>Rishav Verma</h2>
    <p> Web Developer</p>
  </section>
</header>
```

The border has much whitespace and I can't fix the border and text inside it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have attached a image document above, so you can understand what i am pointing too, the borders have so much whitespace in the left and right side hence i want the text inside the border to be fit and does not leave any whitespace

Answer (score -1):

Just add **width:fit-content** to `.welcome`, it will take the width according to content and also make its parent e.g `.header` to be displayed in **grid** and align the content center for align it center on the page.

```css
CSS CODE - * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  header,
  .welcome {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(237, 239, 240);
  padding: 10% 10%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  display:grid;
  justify-content:center;
}

.welcome {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  border: white solid 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  width:fit-content;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section class="welcome" id="welcome-section">
    <h2>Rishav Verma</h2>
    <p> Web Developer</p>
  </section>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need all that code

```css
header {
  background-color: rgb(237, 239, 240);
  padding-block: 10%;
  display: flex;
}

.welcome {
  text-align: center;
  margin-inline: auto;
  border: white solid 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section class="welcome" id="welcome-section">
    <h2>Rishav Verma</h2>
    <p> Web Developer</p>
  </section>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's now fixed, I think i created so many properties that they started colliding